# .each(function(){}) in jquery not working on dynamically created div elements

Tags: jquery, html, popover

I am trying to create tooltip popovers for dynamically created div elements containing images.
I am using a jquery plugin called [Powertip](http://stevenbenner.github.io/jquery-powertip/).

The script I have at the moment does not give me the desired results.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.thumbnail-hoverable').each(function () {
                var mouseOnDiv = $(this);
                var imgsrc = mouseOnDiv.find("img").attr("src").toString();
                console.log(imgsrc);
                var tipContent

                $(function () {
                    tipContent = $('<div class="image-detail-popover"><div  class="img-p

opover-detail-container" style="border: 2px solid #cccccc; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 370px; height: 322px;display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;"><img alt="test" class="clickable" src = "" style="max-height: 322px; max-width: 370px; display: block; margin: auto;" /><img alt="" src="Images/fowto-watermark.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 9999999;" /></div></div>');
                        tipContent.find("div.img-popover-detail-container").children("img").attr("src", imgsrc);
                    });

                    console.log(tipContent.toString());
                    mouseOnDiv.data('powertipjq', tipContent);
                    mouseOnDiv.powerTip({
                        //placement: 'n',
                        mouseOnToPopup: true,

                    });

                    $("img.clickable").click(function () {
                        $(parent.document).find(".ticket-img-container").children("img").attr("src", imgsrc);
                        alert("clicked");
                        console.log("clicked");
                    });

                    $("div.img-popover-detail-container").mouseenter(function () {
                        $(parent.document).find(".ticket-img-container").children("img").attr("src", imgsrc);
                        alert("clicked div");
                        console.log("clicked div");
                    });
                });
            });
       </script>
```

The div element with class thumbnail-hoverable is created dynamically with an asp repeater. But the .each does not work. Actually it works till console.log(imgsrc).  I have to replace .each with .mouseenter, but that defeats the use of Powertip plugin, as it already does that. Also the .click functions do not work, even with mouseenter. I need to click on an element in the popover to set other elements in the main page. Can anybody please help?

Comment: What is the point of `.each(function() {` without parameters, `var tipContent` in the open without `;` and `$(function() {` for that matter?

Answer (score 0):

You mis a ; after the `var tipcontent`

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple issues with the code.

First missing colon after the tipcontent initialization.

```
var tipcontent ;
               ^--- Missing colon
```

- No separation of concerns. (Makes your JS cleaner) .
- Why do you want use $.each to bind the events.

Comment: I thought of using $.each for this reason: The divisions with class thumbnail-hoverable are dynamically created with an asp repeater with using data from a database table, one of them being an url for the src attr of img element. I would like extract this url for each img element created and pass it to the tipcontent, which will then be passed as parameter to the tooltip.

I would appreciate it if you guide me to a better way of doing it...